# Making variables available outside a function without globals

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm struggling to get my head around how to pass information around in javascript. Can some kind person show me how to take a variable from within a function and use it in another function but without making the variable global. I think i need to use return but I am stuck and not sure what to google to get something I can learn from.

For example, how can I make the "json" variable available so i can use it in the "MasterView" function. Thank you in advance.

```
function fetchData() {
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.App.Properties.setString('cachedJson', this.responseText);
        var json = JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString('cachedJson',''));
    },
    timeout: 5000
});

xhr.open("GET", site_url + "?get_json=postObjects");
xhr.send();
}

function MasterView() {};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous ways to go around this without using globals.

Also, what do you mean by "without making the variable global"?
You want to avoid polluting the global namespace or you just don't want your variable to be available in all of your functions?

Here's a way of passing the value from one of your functions to another:

```
function a(){
    var hello = "world";
    return hello;
}

function b(){
    var result = a();
    console.log(result);
}
```

As you can see function a() returns the variable `hello` with the value "world".
Now if you call function b() it will store a()'s return value in a variable called `result` and then log it to the console.

Another option is to use parameters (sometimes called as arguments) in your functions:

```
function a(){
    var hello = "world";
    b(hello);
}

function b(arg){
    console.log(arg);
}
```

In this case if you will call function a() it will instantly call function b(), passing the variable hello, so b() will log "world".
Of course the latter aproach is not always a good choice, i.e. you simply don't want your first function to call another one. In that case you can do the following:

```
function a(){
    var hello = "world";
    return hello;
}

function b(arg){
    console.log(arg);
}
```

Then call function b() as: `b(a());`
This way you'll pass function a()'s return value as an argument to function b().

Hopefully this cleared up most of your questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Simply add this:
var json;
// and continue...
function fetchData() {
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.App.Properties.setString('cachedJson', this.responseText);
            json = JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString('cachedJson',''));
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });

    xhr.open("GET", site_url + "?get_json=postObjects");
    xhr.send();
}
function MasterView() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
};
```

With hopes that it might work...Or:

```
function fetchData() {
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.App.Properties.setString('cachedJson', this.responseText);
            json = JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString('cachedJson',''));
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });

    xhr.open("GET", site_url + "?get_json=postObjects");
    xhr.send();
}
function MasterView() {
    var json;
    fetchData();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Global variables are useful for a lot of things, however if the only variable you need is json, and you only need it in the function Masterview, call the function fetchData from the function MasterView and make fetchData return json.

W3 schools is a great tool for javascript and html development. Try this link for more on functions, specifically functions with a return value.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp